# Lighting up the scene using a fire in cycles

Tags: rendering, fluid-simulation, lighting

I am rendering a torch light scene which looks something like this in my viewport and this is how I want it to actually look, but maybe a bit dimmer and realistic (for which I'm using Cycles).

[image: viewport image]

But this is how it looks while rendering. No details are visible at all. How can I make the fire throw light onto the scene without adding an additional lamp?

[image: processing image]

Also, after the rendering completes, this is how the image looks.

[image: rendered image]

Can someone tell me what's happening here and how to rectify it? And also, how to achieve the desired lighting?

Comment: Do you have an emission-shader added to the fire?

Comment: @MarcoVitale I created the fire using Quick Effects Smoke. So what do I add the emission shader to? The object that is acting as the fire emitter?